# UINavigationController weird issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

In my app I have NavigationController as root, I have a navigation button as well.
When I'm pressed the button it flips to another controller.

**the destination view code:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favorites.plist"];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    NSKeyedUnarchiver *unArchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc]initForReadingWithData:data];

    self.title = [unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
    self.pubDate = [unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"pubdate"];
    self.description = [ unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"description"];
}
```

**Button code 1:**

```
  -(void)navFavoritesButton{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                           forView:self.view cache:YES];
    FavoritesView *fav = [[FavoritesView alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    UINavigationController *favNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:fav];
    favNav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:favNav animated:YES];
}
```

**button code 2:**

```
-(void)navFavoritesButton{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipview" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft
                           forView:self.view cache:YES];
    FavoritesView *fav = [[FavoritesView alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
    fav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:fav animated:YES];

}
```

I'm having a weird problem;
If I'm using button 2 code all works good, the view is loaded, unArchived the data and display it on a tableView.

But if I'm using the button 1 code the app crash with the following log:

```
 2013-04-21 16:51:56.714 YnetXML[21898:f803] -[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b4fd30
2013-04-21 16:51:56.715 YnetXML[21898:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b4fd30'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x268c052 0x1a61d0a 0x268dced 0x25f2f00 0x25f2ce2 0xc312d1 0xc9830e 0x82123 0xc9764e 0xc96c1c 0xcbd56d 0xca7d47 0xcbe441 0xcbe4f9 0xeb5c68 0xc754a1 0xc7612b 0xeb54c7 0xc9e427 0xc9e58c 0x348c4 0xc9e5cc 0x34568 0x387d 0x268dec9 0xbd45c2 0xe0fd54 0x268dec9 0xbd45c2 0xbd455a 0xc79b76 0xc7a03f 0xc792fe 0xbf9a30 0xbf9c56 0xbe0384 0xbd3aa9 0x35a9fa9 0x26601c5 0x25c5022 0x25c390a 0x25c2db4 0x25c2ccb 0x35a8879 0x35a893e 0xbd1a9b 0x22ed 0x2215)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

**EDIT:**

I deleted the line below and it works for both button 1 and 2 code.
What should cause the problem?

```
self.title = [unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
```

what could be the problem? Why it works well without the navigationController and crash with?

I'm trying to solve the problem for several hours, I tried all sorts of ways, I read online but nothing works. I just can not figure out what causes it to crash, help please!

Comment: You should add an exception breakpoint to pinpoint the line where this error occurs. I don't see any reference to an array in the code you posted. Also where are the different pieces of code you posted? Are the button 1 and 2 code snippets in the same controller? Is the viewDidLoad code in a different controller?

Comment: in Button 1 code i have a UINavgationController with the 'fav' as root, in button 2 code there is no UINavgationController..
and yes, they both snippets in the same controller (which has the button). the viewDidLoad is a different controller yes.. the detination controller..

as i can see the error occurs in `[self presentModalViewController:favNav animated:YES];`

Comment: Two things. I tried your button 1 code, and it worked fine, although I don't know what you're doing with that animation code -- the view is flipped without it (and those methods aren't supposed to be used as of iOS 4 anyway). presentModalViewController is also depreciated (although it still works). Obviously, I couldn't do what you're doing in the viewDidLoad method of FavoritesView, so it's possible the error has something to do with that (although I don't know why it would show up in the line you say it does).

Comment: i deleted the animation code, its still works as you said. thank you for that.
but i still have problem with button code 1..
this is not possible that the code in viewDidLoad causes the error, because its working perfect with button code 2.

Comment: updated my post, please read..

Comment: It would have been helpful if you had mentioned in your question that the title was an NSMutableArray, since the error mentions an NSMutableArray. That would have made diagnosing your problem a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem lies with these three statements

```
self.title = [unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
self.pubDate = [unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"pubdate"];
self.description = [ unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"description"];
```

Try this:

```
//I guess problem with this, because only when you bring in a navigation controller , your app crashes so only when navigation controller comes into play the navigation bar appears and self.title is the text you see in the center of the navigation bar - so rename self.title to self.titlesArray or something

if([[unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"title"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
 //do not use self.title for other purposes, it is to set title of navigation bar.
self.title = [unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"title"];
}

self.pubDate = [unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"pubDate"];
self.description= [unArchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"description"];
```

Note: This is not the way to implement but this is just a way to find out whether these statements are the cause for your crash. Try this and tell me, we l figure out another way.

Comment: the title is an NSMutableArray, which get the titles for the tableView..
the pubDate and description is an NSMutableArray as well..

i did a debug and from what i saw the app crashing in the viewDidLoad method..

Comment: self.title is the default variable that is used to set the navigation bar title. So better use another name for the title array and try.

Comment: omggggg dude its fixed my problem!!
thank you thank you thank you!!